# Use same code for desktop Tabs and mobile Accordion - CSS only

Tags: html, css

On small resolution (mobiles) I need to transform tabs into accordions.
This is current HTML:

```
<main>
  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">Tab 1</label>
  <section id="content1">Tab 1 Content</section>

  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">Tab 2</label>
  <section id="content2">Tab 2 Content</section>

  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">Tab 3</label>
  <section id="content3">Tab 3 Content</section>
</main>
```

and the CSS:

```
main {
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}
section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
input:checked + label {
  color: #555;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 2px solid orange;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #content3 {
  display: block;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  main {
    padding-top:0;
  }
  label {
    /*font-size: 0;*/
    text-align:left;
    display:block;
  }
  label:before {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

This works fine on mobiles (as accordion) but `labels` are broken on desktop resolution.

Any idea how can I fix labels horizontally on top? Also needs to have table-cell display.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/templatetuners/98ebjdwn/)

Comment: I just found this and works [link](https://codepen.io/josh_vogt/pen/EaaZbP)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution of your question.

```css
main {
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}
.tabArea {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  position: absolute
}
input {
  display: none;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
label:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input:checked + label {
  color: #555;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 2px solid orange;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #content3,
#tab4:checked ~ #content4 {
  display: block;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  label {
    /*font-size: 0;*/
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
  }
  label:before {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  section {
    position: relative;
  }
  .tabArea {
    border: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  label {
    padding: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="tabArea">


    <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
    <label for="tab1">Tab 1</label>
    <section id="content1">Tab 1 Content</section>

    <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
    <label for="tab2">Tab 2</label>
    <section id="content2">Tab 2 Content</section>

    <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
    <label for="tab3">Tab 3</label>
    <section id="content3">Tab 3 Content</section>

    <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
    <label for="tab4">Tab 4</label>
    <section id="content4">Tab 4 Content</section>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Can't use `absolute` because under the tabs I will have more content